# How to represent this type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

How can i represent a list which include 1 String and another list with maximum of 3 Strings.

Like this one:

```
osztaly = [("András", ["mákos", "meggyes", "almás"]), ("Joli", ["túrós"]), ("Anna", ["almás", "almás"]), ("Tamás", []), ("Mari", ["almás", "meggyes"]), ("Vera", [])]
```

Answer (score 7):

If you just need size 3:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
data ListUpTo3 a
    = Zero
    | One a
    | Two a a
    | Three a a a
    deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

The `Functor`, `Foldable`, and `Traversable` instances recover many (but not all) of the convenient functions available for the builtin lists.

If you may need other sizes than max-3, you can generalize this, but it takes significantly more type-level programming, which adds significant programmer effort both for the implementer of the type and for the user of the type.

Personally, I probably would not try to capture this constraint at the type level. Then the max-length-3 bit is not compiler checked; but it is also much simpler to implement and use. You can read more about this idea elsewhere on the net under the keywords "smart constructor".

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
-- N.B. we do not export the value constructor, only the type constructor
module UpTo3 (ListUpTo3, fromList, toList) where

newtype ListUpTo3 a = ListUpTo3 [a] deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

fromList :: [a] -> Maybe (ListUpTo3 a)
fromList xs = if null (drop 3 xs) then Just (ListUpTo3 xs) else Nothing

toList :: ListUpTo3 a -> [a]
toList (ListUpTo3 xs) = xs
```

Comment: Better to pattern-match against `(_:_:_:_:_)` for the error case, so that `fromList [1..]` returns Nothing instead of diverging.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks, I've updated with a similar fix that makes the `3` more obviously configurable.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that after all this, `osztaly` would have this type signature:  `osztaly :: [(String, ListUpTo3 String)]`